# The Advantages of Binary with regards to Arithmetic

Tags: binary, decimal, cpu-architecture, integer-arithmetic

Does anyone know how the binary systems is better than decimal when doing arithmetic? It was a question in a test and I can't seem to find a good answer anywhere...

In specific:

Explain the benefits of using binary rather than decimal under the following topics-

- integer addition
- integer multiplication
- integer division
- floating point storage

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not necessary for human to use binary system. With the topic, I think your question is more like why computers use it?

Modern computers are based on the electronic circuits. We use a simple 2-state gate to represent information. The basic element in circuits is transistor, which shows high and low voltage, representing 1 and 0 respectively. For a complex circuit, a given input can produce some outputs. If we see that from a high level, it shows the operation of 0's and 1's.

The circuits can also be used for storage, which consists of 0's and 1's, because of the 2-state.

Computer uses the binary system both for storage and operation. If we change it to a decimal system, we have to find a component which has ten state, representing 10 numbers. Besides, we also have to design operation between these basic numbers.

Until now, electronic circuits make it perfect with binary system.

Comment: Some CPUs support binary-coded-decimal math.  This is useful for things like computing exact dollar amounts (because some fractional dollars can't be stored exactly in binary).  But in general, doing math in binary is more compact in terms of the number of logic gates because it maps directly to the sorts of digital signals processed by digital logic.